# In Ansi C - Where is 'decay' defined, and where are all the cases of it occuring documented?

Tags: c

I come across the term 'decay' every now and then, for example when arrays passed in as function parameters decays to a pointer, or when functions decay to a function pointer. If I was writing a c compiler, where would I find the term 'decay' officially defined and where would all the cases of it occuring be documented?

Comment: If you're writing a C compiler you would read the Standard.

Comment: I wrote a C Compiler 3 years ago for my friend's custom CPU that handled everything except arrays and pointers because I realized I needed to understand every nuance due to syntax complexity. I own/read the Ansi C Standard back then and it didn't give me the answers I needed to finish... but I'll look at it again just in case I missed something.

Comment: the entire C language is defined in the Standard, and nothing outside it is legal in C. If you didn't find the answer in there, there is no answer, plain and simple. So you just missed it.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say I read "The (Ansi) C Programming Language" by K & R, which I assumed you meant by "The standard"

Comment: @Seth Carnegie In C11 the only occurrence of "decay" is a footnote: "256) Among other implications, atomic variables shall not decay." AFAIK, C does not define "decay".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official terminology in the standard for this is "lvalue conversion". In the current version of the standard (C11) you find this in 6.3.2.1 p3.

Comment: Ahhh this is it! Now I need to translate that to english, lol!

Answer (score 1):

Second Google search yielded this:

```
The K&R method of reducing arrays to pointers
 ---------------------------------------------
 K&R tried to create a unified treatment of arrays and pointers, one that 
 would expose rather than hide the array equation in the compiler's code. 
 They found an elegant solution, albeit a bit complicated. The "ugly" 
 array equation is replaced in their formulation by four rules:

    1) An array of dimension N is a 1D array with
       elements that are arrays of dimension N-1.

    2) Pointer addition is defined by:

          ptr # n = ptr + n * size(type-pointed-into)

       "#" denotes here pointer addition to avoid 
       confusion with ordinary addition.
       The function "size()" returns object's sizes.

    3) The famous "decay convention": an array is 
       treated as a pointer that points to the 
       first element of the array.

       The decay convention shouldn't be applied
       more than once to the same object.

    4) Taking a subscript with value i is equivalent 
       to the operation: "pointer-add i and then 
       type-dereference the sum", i.e.

          xxx[i] = *(xxx # i)


        When rule #4 + rule #3 are applied recursively 
        (this is the case of a multi-dimensional array), 
        only the data type is dereferenced and not the 
        pointer's value, except on the last step.
```

[Source](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html)

Comment: This is only a partial answer; where is decay defined, what are ALL the known cases of decay. I already google searched and found cases scattered all over (including the one you gave), but I'm looking for the definitive resource where *all* cases are covered.

Comment: I don't know why people are upvoting this as an answer; arrays decaying to pointers is *not* the only case of decay occuring.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard is the only way to answer questions like these.

If you want to buy the official document then you need to look for *ISO/IEC 9899:2011*. Or may prefer the older standards from 1999 or 1989.

Alternatively, the final draft of the 2011 standard is available here, and should be close enough:
 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Answer (score 0):

An array name *decays* means its value is treated (=has type and value) as a pointer to its first element. Note that array names do not always decay (e.g. not as the operand of the sizeof operator). Imperfect synonyms may be *treated as* or *rewritten as* or simply *used as*.